# Separate a list of NSStrings into Paragraphs. Maybe even double spaced?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a `documentInteractionController` that allows me to share info in my app; like the visitors info, operating system they are using, etc. I've created this array of `NSString`s and I'd like them to be separated by paragraphs. So instead of appearing like this:

```
Visitor Location Miami FL currentURL apple.com
```

Rather it would be:

```
Visitor Location    
Miami FL

currentURL
apple.com
```

How would I do this? Make the strings all separated by paragraphs?

```
NSArray *visitorInfoArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Visitor Location", _visitor.location, @"currentURL", _visitor.currentURL, nil];
NSString *visitorInfo = [visitorInfoArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSString *filename = @"User Info";
NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
[visitorInfo writeToURL:tempURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[MTq main:^{
    [FCIProgress dismiss];
    DLog(@"%@", visitorInfo);
    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:tempURL];
    self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"public.plain-text";
    [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}];
```

Comment: Any reason you're storing your info in key/value pairs in an `NSArray` instead of `NSDictionary`?

Comment: First you should read the documentation for NSString and NSArray.  If that isn't sufficient, read it again.

Comment: You are getting into something so deep. Yet you are unaware of the proper class to use for storing a piece of data. I suggest you build up your basics first. Also, what @HotLicks said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to craft your string in a specific way, you probably don't want to use `NSArray`'s `componentsJoinedByString` method. You want to use `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat` instead. Also, if you need to use your array info anywhere after this method, I strongly suggest using a dictionary instead. If you don't use it again, there's no need to create it at all.

To craft your output string:

```
NSString *visitorInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Visitor Location\n%@\n\ncurrentURL\n%@", _visitor.location, _visitor.currentURL];
```

---

If you plan on reusing the info in that `NSArray`, let's put it in an `NSDictionary` so that you can reference values by their `key` rather than remembering an index.

```
NSDictionary *visitorInfoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    _visitor.location, @"visitorLocation",
                                    _visitor.currentURL, @"currentURL",
                                    nil];
```

You can now access your values like so: `[visitorInfoDict objectForKey:@"visitorLocation"]`